# Popup visibility removal successful on first try only

Tags: javascript, scope, settimeout

The following code works in the sense that it cause the alert to appear then disappear after 3 seconds. The problem is, when I trigger it a second time (without refreshing the browser), it will appear but not timeout a second time and disappear unless the x is clicked. How can I make it keep appearing and disappearing on cue without a user x'ing out?

Please see following:

```
function appendWarning () {
    // missing
    if(!result) {
      $(".confirmAlert").append('class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Oh snap! Something went terribly wrong!</div>');
    } else {
        var confPop = $(".confirmAlert").append('<div id="confrimedLuck" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' + rand + '</div>');
        console.log("confPop BANG!");
    }
    var cleanAlert = setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('confrimedLuck').style.display = 'none'}, 3000);
    console.log("cleanAlert executed!");
}
```

Comment: Does it need to disappear 5ever, if the user manually closes it?

Comment: please provide a fiddle so that your issue is clarified.

Comment: @royhowie - So basically it needs to timeout each time and disappear without having to x out. It currently times-out the first time, but each time after the alerts start stacking on top of one another, unless you click the x to remove them.

Comment: I edited your code above because the code was a piece of a function; please edit in some more code so that the whole picture makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you're appending, but then setting display to none every time rather than removing it, so you end up with duplicate elements of the same id, and only select the first one which is already hidden.

Instead of setting display to none, remove it:

```
var cleanAlert = setTimeout(function(){ $('#confrimedLuck').remove() }, 3000);
```

Or if you prefer, you can keep it always present in the DOM while simply toggling its display property (most conveniently with jQuery, since you're already using it).

```
// missing
if(!result) {
  $(".confirmAlert").append('class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Oh snap! Something went terribly wrong!</div>');
} else {
    var confPop = $("#confrimedLuck").show().parent();
    console.log("confPop BANG!");
}
var cleanAlert = setTimeout(function(){ $('#confrimedLuck').hide() }, 3000);
console.log("cleanAlert executed!");
```

Comment: Ups spent so much time without reloading, your answer is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you did only hide the element created on the first call in the timeout (by setting it's `display` property to `none`), because `getElementById` only accesses the first found element with the specified ID this first element get's hidden again and again while the other newly created `confirmedLuck` divs remain unchanged and visible.

This should work:

```
function appendWarning () {
    // missing
    if(!result) {
      $(".confirmAlert").append('class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Oh snap! Something went terribly wrong!</div>');
    } else {
        var confPop = $(".confirmAlert").append('<div id="confrimedLuck" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' + rand + '</div>');
        console.log("confPop BANG!");
    }
    var cleanAlert = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#confrimedLuck').remove(); // Completely remove the element (using jQuery) instead of just hiding it.
    }, 3000);
    console.log("cleanAlert executed!");
}
```